# Source breaks ability to print accents in R

Tags: r, diacritics

I find that while I can `cat` accented Spanish letters:

```
> cat("**                 Retención Probabilidad Estimación                     ** \n")
**                 Retención Probabilidad Estimación                     **
```

for some reason this breaks when I use `source` to source the script containing the `cat`:

```
> source("..//codigo//upn_notas.R")
*************************************************************************** 
**                 RetenciÃ³n Probabilidad EstimaciÃ³n                     ** 
***************************************************************************
```

At first I thought to work around the problem by changing my system locale, but this turns out to go against recommendations as it is not always straight forward and may cause other problems in the system.

I'm not sure why `source` breaks the ability to `print` or `cat` accented characters, but is there a work-around?

Comment: Have you tried using the `encoding=` parameter to `source()`? Do you know what encoding your R file uses?

Comment: @MrFlick I hadn't tried it and don't know much about encoding. However, after reading your comment I tried `encording = "utf-8"` and it worked! Thanks!